# Django and Gunicorn not working properly through systemd

Tags: django, postgresql, gunicorn, systemd

While following [this awesome tutorial](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/) for installing Django with Gunicorn, PostgreSQL and Nginx, I discovered that I couldn't user Supervisor as suggested, because it doesn't work with Python 3.

Since systemd is the default service manager on my Centos 7 server, I created a [unit file](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) to run gunicorn as per the tutorial. However, it failed with errors such as "`no SECRET_KEY set`" and "`no PostgreSQL password supplied`".
Since everything was already working before systemd, these errors were weird.

Like many others, I was saving my secret Django settings as environment variables so as not to be stored publicly in my git repo. However, [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19054008/how-to-use-environment-variables-with-supervisor-gunicorn-and-django-1-6) explained that environment variables in my ~/.bashrc would not be recognised, so I would have to make those variables accessible by systemd.

I have summarised my solution below for anyone who has the same difficulties with running Django through systemd.

**UPDATE**:
The best solution allows systemd to work without compromising Django. While it's possible to state environment variables directly in a systemd unit file, this makes the variables inaccessible to Django when *not* running as a system daemon or debugging via the Python shell.

Answer (score 2):

Just have the systemd unit read the environment from a file with `EnvironmentFile=`.

```
[Service]
EnvironmentFile=-/whatever/django_environment_settings
```

Comment: I clarified my answer.  If you use the EnvironmentFile setting you restrict Django to working _only_ with systemd.

Comment: No, you don't specify the environment variables in the unit file, you point to the external file that contains them. This will continue to work with your  method.