# environment variables using $BASH_ENV with supervisor, gunicorn and django

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, gunicorn, supervisord

With regard to these posts:

[Envs with supervisor, gunicorn & django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19054008/how-to-use-environment-variables-with-supervisor-gunicorn-and-django-1-6),

[How to guarantee availability of $BASH_ENV](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138577/how-to-guarantee-availability-of-bash-env),

I'm trying to figure out why supervisor won't read my $BASH_ENV settings.

I am currently using a setup over which I load a gunicorn start up script through supervisor's config file.

I've set the supervisor's settings like this:

```
# /etc/supervisor/conf.d/test_project.conf

[program:test_project]
command=/home/konos5/gunicorn_start.sh
user=konos5
...
```

and the gunicorn script is this:

```
# /home/konos5/gunicorn_start.sh

#!/bin/bash
...
echo $TEST
...
```

So far so good. Both gunicorn and supervisor run fine. The problem is that `$TEST` comes out empty. Since supervisor loads the gunicorn script from a non-login, non-interactive shell it should source the file specified in `$BASH_ENV`.

Therefore I do this

```
$~ echo 'export TEST="HELLO WORLD"' > ~/my_custom_var
$~ export BASH_ENV=~/my_custom_var
```

The I `reread` and `update` supervisor and start again my project. However `TEST` still comes out empty. How is this possible since $BASH_ENV was supposed to be sourced?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what if you give full path instead of `~`?

Comment: @fedorqui Unfortunately it won't work either way. My best bet is that it must have something to do with the way supervisor works and the chain of inheritance.