# Unable to get environment variable

Tags: python, flask, environment-variables

In my `__init__.py` file I am trying to set:

```
import os
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.environ['MY_KEY']
```

but am getting the error:

```
raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'MY_KEY'
```

When I run `printenv`, the variable `MY_KEY` is present.

Also in `IDLE` I tried running:

```
import os
print os.environ['MY_KEY']
```

and I get the correct output.

I set `MY_KEY` in `/etc/profile` using:

```
export MY_KEY="1234example_secret_key"
```

I did `restart` my computer after making the change to the `profile` file.

Would anyone know what the issue may be?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How are you running your flask app? Not all invocations will evaluate /etc/profile. The system's apache install, for instance, might not, depending on setup.

Comment: @pvg I am using `Nginx/Gunicorn`. I run the app using `supervisor`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19054008/how-to-use-environment-variables-with-supervisor-gunicorn-and-django-1-6
Another, potentially simpler approach is to have this info in a python file and import it. Keep out of source control and have your deploy script generate it. Keep a template version under source control with a different name. So, if you have app_config.py with the params, maintain an app_config_sample.py for documentation purposes. If you wan to get fancy, have your build script generate app_config out of sample.

Comment: @Giri You can pass env variable to supervisor process using environment config param environment = MY_KEY="ABCD",MY_KEY2="EFG".

Comment: @Giri yet another option is to simply not use Flask's default encrypted cookies for sessions and use something like Beaker. No weird secret keys, no sending sensitive data back and forth to the client, the whole thing just goes away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running your process under supervisor and/or gunicorn (judging but you comments you are) you can user supervisor environment config param.

```
[program:my_app]
...
environment = MY_KEY="ABCD",MY_KEY2="EFG"
```

You can also use gunicorn --env flag or env config file param.

```
gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:8000 --env MY_KEY=ABCD test:app
```

The downside of the 2nd option is that your key will be visible to anyone who has access to your machine.

The best approach is to use the app.config.from_envvar function and store your config into machine specific config settings location (this could be on encrypted filesystem). In this case your code would look like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
...
app.config.from_envvar('MACHINE_SPECIFIC_SETTINGS')
```

Your MACHINE_SPECIFIC_SETTINGS env variable could point to the file that will have the MY_KEY value.

```
MACHINE_SPECIFIC_SETTINGS=/path/to/config.py
```

Comment: Thanks @Boris, I will try this out. If I use your final suggestion, how/where should I be setting the `MACHINE_SPECIFIC_SETTINGS` variable?

Comment: @Giri You can use the supervisor environment config param or gunicorn --env flag.